# Will rel=canonical <link> tags work inside <style> tags?

Tags: html, seo, canonical-link

I'm interested in adding canonical link tags to pages for SEO, and I'm wondering if they will function normally if nested inside HTML `<style>` tags. Will something like this work?

```
<html> 
<head>
   <style> 
       <link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com" />
   </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The link element is metadata HTML element, and the canonical is a private case of it. Since it use mainly for SEO - read more here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

No, `<link>` elements are HTML; a `<style>` element can only contain CSS. You can tell from the syntax highlighting of your code that the `<link>` element isn't being highlighted quite the same as the rest of the markup. `<link>` elements need to be directly in the `<head>` element, not in a `<style>` element.

That `<link>` element simply isn't going to work correctly. I'd be surprised if any search engine crawlers special-cased it.